# How to Plot a Vector Field and a Curve on a Single Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to plot a vector field and a circle using the following code. With the code as it is, the blue circle appears off-center. If I comment out that draw command and un-comment the other, the blue circle does not plot at all. Why is this happening? How can it be fixed? I feel like there is something really simple I'm missing.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\def\length{sqrt(1+(x+y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm,scale=1.85,font=\footnotesize]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        view={0}{90},
        domain=-2.5:2.5,
        samples=18,
        axis equal image,
        ticklabel style = {font=\tiny}
        ]
        \addplot3[
        gray,
        quiver={u={1/(\length)},
        v={(x+y)/(\length)},
        scale arrows=0.2,
        every arrow/.append style={-latex}}
        ] (x,y,0);
        % \draw (axis cs:0,0) circle [blue, radius=1];
    \end{axis}
    \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` to have the coordinate system inside the `axis` environment sychonized for `\path` (as well as for `\draw`, `\fill` and similar) macros. This way, you can omit `axis cs`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, scale=1.85, font=\footnotesize]
    \def\length{sqrt(1+(x+y)^2)}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        view={0}{90},
        domain=-2.5:2.5,
        samples=18,
        axis equal image,
        ticklabel style={font=\tiny}
    ]
    \addplot3[
        gray,
        quiver={u={1/(\length)},
        v={(x+y)/(\length)},
        scale arrows=0.2,
        every arrow/.append style={-latex}},
    ] (x,y,0);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]